# How to use table inside a newenvironment

Tags: tables, line-breaking, environments, underline

I'm using a table inside a new environment to create a list of definitions, but some of the things being defined are two words. I want to have the first word on one line and the other word on the next line but everything I try gives an error or an incorrect out. (This works fine if it's only one word.) Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{defn}[2]
  {\begin{tabular}{p{1in} p{5in}}
  \hfill\underline{#1} & #2
  }
  {\\ \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
{Jib\\ Jab} {Here is the definition of the word Jib Jab}
\end{example}

\begin{defn}
{Def2} {Here is the definition of the word Def2}
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your problem is `\underline{Jib\\ Jab}` which is not allowed us for underlining words. Welcome to site!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Do you like to obtain something like this?

[image]

Command `\underline{...}` doesn't allow to break the underlined text. This can be done for example with use of package `soul`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{defn}[2]
  {\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{1in} p{5in}}
\hfill\ul{#1} & #2
  }
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
{Jib\\ Jab}{Here is the definition of the word Jib Jab}
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}
{Def2} {Here is the definition of the word Def2}
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```